# Оповещение о завершении сессии

Tags: сессия, php, javascript

Добрый день!
У меня есть один мой проект, web-сайт на языке PHP. На нем используется HTML, CSS, JS, БД mySQL - впрочем, как и почти везде. И тут у меня появилась проблема. При изменении сессии пользователя в базе данных мне нужно выполнять функцию js, который в свою очередь сообщит пользователю, что его сессия завершена.
Подскажите, как организовать данный скрипт, чтобы не изобретать велопипед. Была идея написать PHP-скрипт, который вызывался бы каждые 5 секунд с помощью JS-функции, но это не самая лучшая идея, из-за нее идет много запросов к серверу. Говорят, можно как-то все это через PHP Sockets сделать, но я не нашел такого решения в Интернете. Заранее благодарю, если поможете, также попрошу не кидать в меня тапочки. Ни разу не сталкивался с подобным скриптом.

Comment: Фраза "при изменении сессии пользователя в базе данных" означает "при поступлении на склад сферического коня в вакууме оприходовать в кубе". Сервер отвечает на запросы, если запрос произошел _позже_ некоторого времени, заданного в прошлом в будущее, сервер демонстрирует, что оно истекло. А чтобы именно в тот момент, когда истекло, передать что-то в браузер, нужна push-технология (типа сокетов, ага), но главное, что на сервере должен быть резидент, иначе как вообще событие произойдет.

Comment: Тема сокетов не слишком сложна, и инфы куча. Стоит почитать. Хотя смысл этого функционала не ясен, если все происходит без аякса  и   в принципе не в реалтайме, чем не угодно оповещение при перезагрузке страницы?

Comment: @Yurez322, а чего именно Вы хотите добиться?

Вам нужно, чтобы изображаемая в браузере страница изменилась (например, на страницу авторизации), если пользователь слишком долго ничего не делал?

Тогда сделайте это на уровне JS страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Внятный вариант делать это для старых браузеров только один - ajax запрос с задержкой ответа. Т.е. постоянно вызывать сервер на стороне клиента, ожидая статус сессии в ответе. А на сервере задерживать ответ, пока не возникнет соотв. событие. Таким образом, у нас будет постоянно висеть соединение для каждого клиента.

Самый топорный вариант, который приходит в голову для "удержания" сервером ответа, - цикл, в котором будет с задержкой производиться опрос сессии (где и как реализована сессия - отдельный вопрос). Как только сессия завершилась, прекращаем цикл и возвращаем ответ, где пишем, что сессия закончилась. Либо по истечении времени, разрешенного на работу скрипта (30 секунд), возвращаем ответ, где пишем, что сессия - ок.

Таким образом, нагрузка на сервер остается та же, но частота запросов сокращается до максимального времени выполнения скрипта. Плюс вместо большого количества входящих запросов будет большое количество одновременных подключений.

Более адекватный вариант - постоянно запущенный кроном скрипт (перезапуск по интервалу, разрешенному для локально запущенных скриптов), который мониторит список всех сессий и, получив идентификатор завершенной сессии, шлет в вебсокет браузеру сообщение. Работает, понятное дело, только в html5. Примеры по сокетам в сети есть, например, [чаты](http://habrahabr.ru/company/ifree/blog/209864/).